# how do I use JIRA automation to check if an issue with a specific summary text exists in an Epic

Tags: jira-automation

How do I use JIRA automation to check if there exists an issue with a specific summary text in an Epic?  And if it does not exist, then create it.

I don't know if that's possible, that's why I'm asking.  I've tried using `For Stories` branch but if the Epic doesn't have any sub issues, then the `For Stories` loop won't even get triggered.